# QML visible property in Grid delete Item

Tags: qt, qt4, qml

I'm trying to create a QML keyboard with the following code on Qt4.8.

```
Item {
    id: keyboard
    property string keys: "azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn****^<"

    Rectangle {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width

        Grid {
            id: keyboardGrid

            rows: 4
            columns: 10
            spacing: 1

            Repeater {
                model: keys.length

                KeyboardButton {
                     visible: { (keys.charAt(index) == "*") ? false : true; }
                    btnKeyText: keys.charAt(index);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've put some '*' in keys in order to make some invisible button to go to the next line of the grid, but when I set a KeyboardButton to `visible = false`, QML interpreter just ignore it.

See the screenshots for more detail, first one is with this code, second one is when I comment the line where i set visible to false.

[image: Invisible * Button]

[image: Visible * Button]

Why invisible components are just ingored ? Any tricks ?

Comment: `Item`s which are not visible are not rendered at all and just ignored (resulting in your visual error). Use `opacity: 0`.

Comment: The same thing append with opacity.

Comment: Oh sorry...it would behave correctly in Quick. In Declarative both `visible: false` and `opacity: 0` gives the same behaviour: the element is not rendered ([see here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#behavioral-changes)). That's the default behaviour. In Quick `Item`s with zero `opacity` are rendered, resulting in the correct spacing. Adding a background and matching that color, wouldn't be an option, I guess. Right?

Comment: Yes, if I set "*" keys to white, it is OK. But only if I have a unchanging background color. So, I've searched for another turn around, and I had to change a little bit of my code to do what I wanted. But, just by using a Repeater and a Row, I was able to create my own custom grid.

Comment: Oh, so you solved the issue by splitting the `Grid` is three `Row`s. Simple and clever. For the record, if possible, please provide the current solution as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna answer my own question ASAP.

Comment: You can use Rectangle with transparent background color ("transparent" or "#00000000").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BaCaRoZzo says, element with `opacity: 0` or `visibility: 0` the element is not rendered (in Qt4.8, in 5 and superior `opacity : 0` does not affect rendering), so I have found another way to do what I wanted.

I achieve this by creating my own grid with a `Repeater` and `Row`s as follow :

```
Item {
    id: keyboard
    property variant keys: ["azertyuiop", "qsdfghjklm", "wxcvbn,;:!", "⇧* ↵←"]

    Repeater{
        id: lineRpt
        model: 4

        anchors.fill: parent

        Row {
            spacing: 1

            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.top
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 25+(index*52)

            anchors.left: parent.left

            property string currentLine: keys[index]

            Repeater {
                model: keys.length

                KeyboardButton {
                     visible: { (keys.charAt(index) == "*") ? false : true; }
                    btnKeyText: keys.charAt(index);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Edit after comments:***

You can also set the background color to transparent, and in my case, I need to remove de "*" of the text too.